# How can I add or remove subviews based on the orientation of the device?

Tags: ios, swift, subview

So I have a button which when clicked calls a function which adds some custom subviews to the view. So what I want is when the device is in portrait mode show me 4 subviews and when you rotate it to landscape show me only one. I want to do something like this:

```
func showSubviews {
  if deviceOreintation == portrait{
  //show 4 subviews 
  }
  else{
  //show 1 subview and hide rest of the three
  }    
 }
```

I tried something like this:

```
 func showSubviews(){  
 if self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Regular {
 //show 4 subviews 
}
else{
 //show 1 subview and hide the rest three
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. You just need to override the `viewWillTransitionToSize(_:withTransitionCoordinator:)` method in your view controller and do some checking there.

Answer (score 0):

- In storyboard, I add 3 views named: red, green, blue with autolayout:

  - all: fixed width, height, center X
  - red: top
  - green: center Y
  - blue: bottom

  [image]
- add this line in viewDidLoad

  ```
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("didChangeOrientation"), name: UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, object: nil)
  ```
- Add new func:

  ```
    func didChangeOrientation() {

       let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation

       if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) {

           green.hidden = true
           print("landscape")
       }
       else {
           green.hidden = false
           print("portrait")
       }
   }
  ```

Hope this can help.